# Fixed Time on a Clock

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to make a javascript clock (done already) which displays a specific time, and the same time, to everyone who views it. Currently, it will display 16:... for me, and 21:.... for the other guy. This is due to timezones, obviously. But, I'd like for it to display one time for every viewer. I already have a code pen set up with the full java script, plus an example of what I need.

http://codepen.io/Connor3xL/pen/wzWPKW

```
       "use strict";

        var textElem = document.getElementById("clocktext");
        var textNode = document.createTextNode("");
        textElem.appendChild(textNode);
        var curFontSize = 24;  // Do not change

        function updateClock() {
            var d = new Date();
            var s = "";
            s += (10 > d.getHours  () ? "0" : "") + d.getHours  () + ":";
            s += (10 > d.getMinutes() ? "0" : "") + d.getMinutes() + ":";
            s += (10 > d.getSeconds() ? "0" : "") + d.getSeconds();
            textNode.data = s;
            setTimeout(updateClock, 1000 - d.getTime() % 1000 + 20);
        }

        function updateTextSize() {
            var targetWidth = 0.9;  // Proportion of full screen width
            for (var i = 0; 3 > i; i++) {  // Iterate for better better convergence
                var newFontSize = textElem.parentNode.offsetWidth * targetWidth / textElem.offsetWidth * curFontSize;
                textElem.style.fontSize = newFontSize.toFixed(3) + "pt";
                curFontSize = newFontSize;
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        updateTextSize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateTextSize);
```

Hope there's somebody who can help.
P.S: If the solution is obvious, feel free to scold me :p

Comment: use [`getUTCHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) rather than just `getHours`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single time for every viewer and you don't care what that time is, you should use UTC time.  Change the getHours and getMinutes calls to getUTCHours and getUTCMinutes.  (Some timezones are offset by 15, 30, or 45 minutes from ours).

Technically, you should also change getSeconds to getUTCSeconds, but I am not aware of a timezone that differs on seconds.

If you don't want to use UTC time as your single time, you should either use an offset from UTC time or base your time on a server time.